# vue-pdf-embed Inline worker is not supported on jest

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

I am using Vue 3 + Jest 28.
I've decided do try `vue-pdf-embed`, which worked great.

The problem is when I run jest.

It says

```
  Inline worker is not supported
```

With this I can't proceed and got stuck.

My `jest.config.ts` looks like this:

```
const esModules = ['quasar', 'quasar/lang', 'lodash-es', 'cnpj'].join('|');

module.exports = {
  verbose: true,
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  testEnvironmentOptions: {
    url: 'http://localhost/',
    customExportConditions: ['node', 'node-addons'],
  },
  globals: {
    'ts-jest': {
      tsconfig: '<rootDir>/tests/tsconfig.json',
      isolatedModules: true,
    },
  },
  collectCoverageFrom: ['src/**/*.{vue,js,ts}', '!src/*.{js,ts}', '!**/typings/**', '!src/**/definitions/*.ts'],
  coverageProvider: 'v8',
  setupFiles: [
    '<rootDir>/tests/jest.init.ts',
  ],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/tests/setupTests.ts'],
  moduleFileExtensions: [
    'vue',
    'js',
    'ts',
    'json',
    'jsx',
    'tsx',
  ],

  transform: {
    // See https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html#transformignorepatterns-array-string
    [`^(${esModules}).+\\.js$`]: 'babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.(ts|js|html)$': 'ts-jest',
    // vue-jest uses find-babel-file, which searches by this order:
    //  (async) .babelrc, .babelrc.js, package.json, babel.config.js
    //  (sync) .babelrc, .babelrc.js, babel.config.js, package.json
    // https://github.com/tleunen/find-babel-config/issues/33
    '.*\\.vue$': '@vue/vue3-jest',
    '.+\\.(css|styl|less|sass|scss|svg|png|jpg|ttf|woff|woff2)$':
      'jest-transform-stub',
  },

  transformIgnorePatterns: [`node_modules/(?!(${esModules}))`],

  moduleNameMapper: {
    '@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
    '^quasar$': 'quasar/dist/quasar.esm.prod.js',
    'lodash-es': 'lodash',
  },

  snapshotSerializers: ['<rootDir>/node_modules/jest-serializer-vue'],
};
```

I've tried so far to add it to the `esModules` variable I have in my jest config but no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came with a reasonable answer: mock the component:

In `jest.init.ts`, which I refer to in my `jest.config.ts` above, I put the following:

```
jest.mock('vue-pdf-embed', () => () => '<mock-vue-pdf-embed/>');
```

and now everything works just fine ;)